# Android google drive app not shown in list of available picture sources

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have enabled import of pictures to my application with the following code:

```
Intent importIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
importIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(importIntent, REQUEST_IMPORT_IMAGE);
```

and it's all fine and dandy, I get the source chooser with gallery and dropbox choices on both my galaxy tab and galaxy nexus.

But when I install and configure the Google drive app it doesn't show up as a choice for image source. Is there some extra hoop involved with importing images from the drive app, or is this  just an oversight from the drive app developer team?

Tried searching the world over, but couldn't find anyone even mention the lack of import from drive app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this all was just a simple overlook by the Android Drive developers. At least after the http://googledrive.blogspot.fi/2013/05/a-smoother-drive-app-for-android.html update the drive app appears as an import source just as it should.

No code changes from my part needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the appropriate intent-filter in the app manifest? Check the Google Drive SDK documentation for guidelines on how to integrate with Android:

https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this the other way round? I have no problem importing images from drive by going to the app and selecting send on an image. It's the invocation of Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT from my own app that's missing the drive option in the dialog.